# How to prevent div to included in a cycle of cycle plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using cycle plugin like

```
   <div id="rol">
    <img />
    <img />
     . 
     .
    </div>

       $("#rol").cycle();
```

and i am making the same div (id = rol) resizable also. using jquery ui

```
   $("#rol").resizable();
```

now after making it resizable, jquery ui will dynamically added some `<div>` as a child of div (id = rol) so it looks something like

```
   <div id="rol">
    <img />
    <img />
     . 
     .
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     .
     .
   </div>
```

Now my problem is that the cycle plugin using those dynamically added div also in its cycle.How do i prevent those div to include in cycle? Is there any option in `cycle plugin` itself so it will cycle only `img tags` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#rol').cycle({ slideExpr: 'img' });
```